# Laptop doesn't shutdown or restart completely - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Dell Inspiron 15

Tags: boot, 16.04, shutdown, bios

Installed Ubuntu 16.04 after changing Boot mode from UEFI Mode to Legacy BIOS mode

But Whenever i try to shutdown or restart using either command line or normal method **never** works

It shows the screen for shutting down and after few sec it goes blank screen which looks like it has shut down properly but it hasn't

I realized this when i tried to restart the laptop. That did the same thing. I had to force shutdown but pressing and holding the power button and then press again to start it up. Same thing i had to do while shutting down.

That drained all the battery, at first i thought the laptop is broken. But it was actually due to not shutting down completely.

**Help Me**

Is the grub configuration problem

I tried editing this on grub file

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq acpi=force"
```

and

```
sudo update-grub
```

did not work for me

Originally when i bought the laptop it had Ubuntu 14.04 and wanted latest

**any solutions?**